# I do it on the whois command and it writes me this error [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this my code

kdoje is my command a'm czech

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['user','info'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kdoje(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    #Datum jointu
    created_at = member.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    joined_at = member.joined_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")#Here you get the time the member joined at and format it, like you formatted member.created_at
    #Embed
    em= discord.Embed(title=member.name, description = member.mention, color = ctx.author.Colour)
    #footer
    em.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f"Příkaz byl vyvolán {ctx.author.name}")
    em.add_field(name = "Datum jointu", value = joined_at) 
    em.add_field(name = "Datum jointu", value = created_at)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

and this error

```
Ignoring exception in command kdoje:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", 
line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "main.py", line 141, in kdoje
em.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.member.avatar_url)
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'member'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", 
line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", 
line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", 
line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 
'Context' object has no attribute 'member'
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code provided, but in the line `em.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.member.avatar_url)`. if this is in your function `kdoje`, use `em.set_thumbnail(url = member.avatar_url)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of **Chuaat** and my findings here the answer:

**First:** It looks like you did not provide the full code as I could not find the following in your code:

```py
em.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.member.avatar_url)
# Change to
em.set_thumbnail(url = member.avatar_url)
```

**Second:** The way you are requesting the `color` of the embed is wrong. `Colour` is not existing/blocks sending the embed. Instead you have to use:

```py
color=ctx.author.color
```

**The full code:**

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['user', 'info'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kdoje(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    created_at = member.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    joined_at = member.joined_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    em = discord.Embed(title=member.name, description=member.mention, color=ctx.author.color)
    em.set_footer(icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url, text=f"Příkaz byl vyvolán {ctx.author.name}")
    em.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    em.add_field(name="Datum jointu", value=joined_at)
    em.add_field(name="Datum jointu", value=created_at)

    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```